# Ordering non-english letters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a client who just sent me the following in regards to order their letters. They are from Finland.

> In our alphabet the letters å, ä and ö are at the very end of the alphabet. Therefore names starting with those should also be after the letter z, not under "a" or "o".

This is the first I've heard of this. Is there a way I could make these letters show at the end of a alphabetical list using MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably the collation of that table is `utf8_general_ci`. Try this,

```
SELECT..
FROM..
WHERE..
ORDER BY text COLLATE utf8_bin
```

- [**SQLFiddle DEMO** (utf8_bin vs utf8_general_ci)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9572e/1)

Comment: Thanks Kuya! Does adding the COLLATE utf8_bin effect any other languages or would that be ok for all languages?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick a collation that fits your ordering and encoding requirements. A list of them can be fetched with:

```
SHOW COLLATION
```

You should be able to set the collation on your connection, and tables and associated data can also be set with defaults. Some statements also support specifying the collation for ordering purposes.

I remember `utf8_swedish_ci` being the default for a long time presumably because MySQL was created by a [Finn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Widenius) while working in Sweden. Later that was changed to `utf8_general_ci` to be more neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Best use ASCII coding/indexing
as multilingual www.qfree.com.au
can be any language display