# set language for eloquent alphabetic orderBy

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent, sql-order-by

I want to sort an alphabetical column and using the orderBy method in Laravel eloquent.

like below:

`Post::where("some conditions")->orderBy('name','desc')->get();`

I'm working with the Persian language and the result seems to use the Arabic alphabet.

I want to change this default alphabet only. can eloquent and MySql handle this at all?

Comment: What charset are you using in your MySQL database?

Comment: @HTMHell utf8mb4 with utf8mb4_bin collation for this column of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer in how you could accomplish this in MySQL:

[Ordering non-english letters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410609/ordering-non-english-letters-in-mysql)

Here's how to configure a default collation setting in Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#read-and-write-connections

Or you could use Laravel's raw system to add collation yourself on the specific query:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: changing collation to utf8mb4_persian_ci was helpful but is there any way to pass the desire collation with the ```orderBy()``` method ??

Comment: @Hossein yes, you would do orderBy raw instead. The third link in the answer covers raw expressions, there's ways to just do raw for orderby, where, etc also in the documentaiton.